# How to add cocos2d into current project?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing my project, but I found that the cocos2D project is quite useful, how can I add the the cocos2d into current project? thz.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest running through the [Cocos2D programming guide](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index).  Your questions is covered in **Lesson 1**.

Comment: Lesson 1 covers exactly what Tattat _doesn't_ want to do.

Comment: Maybe. Regardless the Cocos2D wiki is a great resource.

Answer (score -3):

1> as Rob's link suggested, download and add cocos2d to your current project;

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_1._install_test

And you need to decide which version you need to download, cocos2d 1.x or 2.0.
If you want to support old device like iphone 1g 2g, then I suggest you stick with cocos2d 1.x
If you want some fancy shader, then you need to consider cocos2d 2.0

2>Since your current project is based on xcode uikit, you need to learn how to integrate 
cocos2d scene into exsiting uikit.

3>of course keep learning cocos2d, it's quite useful
 :)

Comment: This doesn't help at all. He asked how to add cocos2d to an existing project.

Comment: @Vladimir: His question is too general,so my answer has to be general... If you think my answer is not helping, can you post a better one ?